# Trying to get a usb modem to run with wvdial

Tags: debian, modem, usb-device, wvdial

```
  $ sudo wvdialconf
    Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

    Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

    ttyS0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
    ttyS0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 115200 baud
    ttyS0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.
    Modem Port Scan<*1>: S1   S2   S3   

Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?

Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial
```

The link shared does not work, any ideas ?

Comment: It is very likely you need to switch the mode of your device with `usb_modeswitch` tool in order to be recognized as modem (not usb storage). But you have to know very precisely the model type to pass proper parameters.

Comment: Here is a link to the FAQ:

https://web.archive.org/web/20090609004950/http://alumnit.ca/wiki/index.php?page=WvDialFAQ

They wayback machine can be a lifesaver! I'm not sure how persistent that link will be though.